# Custom AutoCompletevView like facebook comments field in android

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-custom-view, autocompletetextview

I want to make custom AutoCompleteView like this..

[image]

It should be populated when my special character is added (like facebook.. When you type @B then all friends those name starts with 'B' will be populated and we can select name).

It should not be populate while typing until '@' is added.

When '@' is added autocompleteview is dropped down and we can select name and after selecting it will be appended.

[image]

I found [this](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/custom-autocomplete-for-android.html) but not satisfied. I need clue. They have implemented...like when you type '@' dropdown populates.But I have to customize more. Right now I need help if other is having idea or any in-completed source.

I have to try myself but let me ask before implementing customview to save my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make custom autocompleteview by extending class.. and code mentioned in your question to be changed.

```
public class CustomAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {
private String previous = "";
private String seperator = "@";
boolean isState = false;

public CustomAutoComplete(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
        final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.setThreshold(1);

}

public CustomAutoComplete(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setThreshold(1);
}

public CustomAutoComplete(final Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setThreshold(1);
}

/**
 * This method filters out the existing text till the separator and launched
 * the filtering process again
 */
@Override
protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {
    String filterText = text.toString().trim();
    String lastchar = filterText.substring(filterText.length() - 1,
            filterText.length());
    if (filterText.length() == 1) {
        if (lastchar.equals(seperator)) {
            isState = true;
        } else {
            isState = false;
        }
    }
    previous = filterText.substring(0,
            filterText.lastIndexOf(getSeperator()) + 1);

    filterText = filterText.substring(filterText
            .lastIndexOf(getSeperator()) + 1);

    if ((lastchar.equals(seperator)) || isState) {
        super.performFiltering(filterText, keyCode);

        isState = true;

    }
}

/**
 * After a selection, capture the new value and append to the existing text
 */
@Override
protected void replaceText(final CharSequence text) {
    isState = false;
    super.replaceText(previous + text);// + getSeperator());

}

public String getSeperator() {
    return seperator;
}

public void setSeperator(final String seperator) {
    this.seperator = seperator;
}

}
```

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`. Just implement your own `Tokenizer` class and it works. For mentions I have written a class you can use it.

```
package howdysam.com.howdysuggesttext;

import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;


public class AtTokenizer implements MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer {

    @Override
    public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;

        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '@') {
            i--;
        }
        while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == '@') {
            i++;
        }

        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;
        int len = text.length();

        while (i < len) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == '@') {
                return i;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        return len;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
        int i = text.length();

        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == '@') {
            i--;
        }

        if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == '@') {
            return text;
        } else {
            if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + "@");
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                        Object.class, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            } else {
                return text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on View section (Activity or Fragment) instead of doing

```
 edit.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

do following

```
edit.setTokenizer(new AtTokenizer());
```

It works.