# Show all items in AutocompleteTextView without writing text

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a AutocompleteTextView and it works fine. When I write a word it shows the relevant result but I want to show all items without writing any word in AutocompleteTextView. How can I do that.

Comment: Try this link code may be help you....


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224027/custom-autocompletevview-like-facebook-comments-field-in-android/15247212#15247212

Comment: It is not the actual solution that I want. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You need to extend AutoCompleteTextView,

> "When threshold is less than or equals 0, a threshold of 1 is
>   applied.".

[setThreshold](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setThreshold%28int%29)

```
import android.content.Context;  
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class InstantAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
            Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
       if (focused && getFilter()!=null) {
        performFiltering(getText(), 0);
    }
    }

}
```

in xml

```
<AutoCompleteTextView ... /> to <your.namespace.InstantAutoComplete ... />
```

EDIT  1

Create new class named InstantAutoComplete  then put this code into the class.

In your layout xml use this class like

then find this widget in your actity (onCreate method).

[Look at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477336/how-to-make-custom-textview)

Comment: But the problem is I already extends Activity in that class and it is required. So cannot able to extend AutoCompleteTextView like your solution. Is there any way.

Comment: You dont need to extend your activty, it is new custom autocomplete textview, just create it and use in your layout. Pls look at edited answer

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/68130108/AutoComplateTextView.rar   look at this example

Comment: I get java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performFiltering(AutoCompleteTextView.java:841) at com.mybusiness.ui.view.InstantAutoComplete.onFocusChanged(InstantAutoComplete.java:35). Any suggestions?

Comment: Works but doesn't show suggestions the first time when it receives focus. How do I rectify this?

Comment: "When threshold is less than or equals 0, a threshold of 1 is applied." What a crappy idea... But thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: This is a InstantAutoComplete, if you not put more code you will get errors in a future, not recommended to me

Comment: @bentzy add a check for `getFilter()` to be non-null before calling `performFiltering()`

Comment: It seems `showDropDown()` still needs to be called along with `performFiltering(...)`, because sometimes the dropdown does not appear.

Comment: TextInputLayout does not seems to work properly with the extended version of AutoCompleteTextView. Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I have one question. I'm clearing my screen once user clicks on submit button, then im supposed to clear screen, im doing autotv.settext("") but soon after that suggestion drop down opening again. where as i want that  only when user clicks on that autocompleteTextview. How can i do that ?

Comment: See a solution of Jan Moravec (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52895155/2914140) to show the list on every click.

Answer (score 58):

> BETTER SOLUTION HERE

You don't need to customize your `AutoCompleteTextView`. Instead just call `autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()` Whenever you need it.....cheers :)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not always work.  I'm not sure why, but on some devices seem to ignore the command when the text field is empty.

Comment: did you set any threshold value for it?

Comment: Yes, 0.  I even call requestFocus beforehand

Comment: This will only work first time.
But if you write something and then clear it, It will show nothing.
That is because you trying to show the popup for the current state of the adapter which is empty after filtering with empty string.

Comment: @SimonKarmy The popup doesn't show even when the dataset is not empty but the text is. Whenever filtering is performed with empty string I populate the dataset with some stored values.

Comment: You should use showDropDown() in both OnFocusChangeListener when focus = true and in OnTextChangeListener say  afterTextChanged, when length = 0;

Answer (score 33):

It Works for me:

add to your object next event methods:

```
    myView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)
                myView.showDropDown();

        }
    });

    myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            myView.showDropDown();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think you need both. Doesn't touching the View give it focus as well?

Comment: It works for me. But I had to add "auto_complete_text_view.threshold = 1 " in addition with your answer

Answer (score 18):

This works for me perfectly, this is an easy way to resolve the problem:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, usernameLists);
etUsername.setThreshold(1);
etUsername.setAdapter(adapter);
etUsername.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
        if (usernameLists.size() > 0) {
                // show all suggestions
                if (!etUsername.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(null);
                etUsername.showDropDown();
            }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: adapter.getFilter().filter(etUsername.getText().toString()); keeps the filter.

Comment: thanks for "adapter.getFilter().filter(null);" it helps me show all items even autocompletetextview was filled with default value.

Comment: this activates dropdown even when I scroll through form

Comment: It works, but as in other answers, it hides and shows the list on every click inside `AutoCompleteTextView`. Also after you typed a letter (and shrinked records count) it will show the full list when click.

Answer (score 9):

You need to call `requestFocus();` to show keyboard, otherwise keyboard does not pop up.

The method forcefully shows drop-down list.

```
autocomptv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            autocomptv.showDropDown();
            autocomptv.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for `requestFocus()`! A good idea! It works, but don't forget to set `autocomptv.threshold = 1` (or `android:completionThreshold="1"`). Without it a list will hide after you type the first letter (and then appear again after the second letter).

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107105/android-button-has-setontouchlistener-called-on-it-but-does-not-override-perform and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065086/custom-view-has-setontouchlistener-called-on-it-but-does-not-override-performcli/32065442 to avoid warnings.

Comment: it still allows to write text

Answer (score 8):

you need to put those steps to make it work perfectly

1-in your xml put this

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/account_type_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edt_with_border"
            android:completionThreshold="0"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
            android:hint="@string/account_type"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sp"
             />
```

you just need to set `android:completionThreshold` to zero

2- in your java code put

```
  mViewDataBinding.accountTypeSpinner.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
        if (hasFocus)
            mViewDataBinding.accountTypeSpinner.showDropDown();
    });
```

Comment: It works, but if you press Back (and hide the list) and then click inside `AutoCompleteTextView` again, it won't show the list. After you type and erase symbols it will show the list.

Comment: this is happening because I use only `setOnFocusChangeListener` you could add `setOnClickListener` and repeat the same code and it should do the trick

Comment: Thanks! I tried other solutions as well. I understood that the list will hide on every click inside `AutoCompleteTextView`. So, when using `setOnClickListener` it hides and shows the list (except first click).

Answer (score 4):

use this :

```
 text.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                text.showDropDown();
                return false;
            }
            });
```

Comment: must be the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
Nothing Custom Required.
```

> I tried All solutions but in some case that does not work. For Example
>   one solution work for first time but when you remove text it will not
>   appear. So I dug more and found following solution.
>
> Suggestions are welcome.

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Hint Here" />


                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Kotlin:

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter<BusinessNoResult>(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, listItems)
autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter)
//threshold specifies the minimum number of characters the user has to type in 
//the
//edit box before the drop down list is shown
autoComplete.threshold = 0

//we have to add check for 0 number of character in edit text. When that 
//happens, we will show pop up manually
autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        //first check if length of input is 0
        if(s?.length ?: 0 == 0){
            //if you don't use handler with post delay, the API will hide pop 
            //up, even if you show it. There could be better ways to this, but 
            //I have implemented this and after 100 millis it gives an animated 
            //look
            Handler().postDelayed({
                //manually show drop down
                autoComplete.showDropDown()
            }, 100) // with 100 millis of delay
        }
    }
})
//when user focus out the view, drop down vanishes. When come back it will not 
//show, so to cover this scenario add following.
autoComplete.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    //when gain focus manually show drop down
    if(hasFocus)
        autoComplete.showDropDown()
}
```

Comment: I removed `BusinessNoResult`, added `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01'`, changed `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` to `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` and `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` to `AutoCompleteTextView`. As in other solutions, it shows the list, but when you click again or press Back button, it then won't show the list until write some symbols.

Answer (score 2):

All answers are outdated. With material design, it becomes a lot easier and smooth. Make sure you put inputType as none for not to open the keyboard anymore.

XML

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/et_countries_list"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:hint="Demo hint"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/countries_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Then just add prepare your adapter and add it.

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new String[]{
                "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain", "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"});
       
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You are done. It will work better than a spinner. You can set hint, error, helper as well.

Answer (score 1):

If other solutions does not work for you try this instead. Popup is displayed **always** on click.

```
   public class InstantAutoComplete extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            performClick();
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        if (getFilter() != null && !isPopupShowing()) {
            performFiltering(getText(), 0);
            showDropDown();
        }
        return super.performClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Probably `onTouchEvent` is not needed. It shows the list when click. First hides and then shows. I think, this is a behaviour of the spinner to hide on many events.

Comment: First it worked very well until I added `InstantAutoComplete` to a complex layout. Then the keyboard started to hide. If revert back to `AutoCompleteTextView` it shows the keyboard and works as expected, but doesn't show full list ot items. If I remove all 3 methods inside `InstantAutoComplete`, it doesn't show the keyboard and even doesn't work as `AutoCompleteTextView`. Maybe some other attributes in the layout are guilty. So, it is a good solution, but check in complex layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Here an approach with onclicklistener as I found tat onTouch was a bit irritating when trying to scroll. mOccupation is the AutocompleteTextView in question.

```
    mOccupation=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv_occupation);
    ArrayAdapter<String> occupationAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> 
    (NewClientActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.occupation_array));
    mOccupation.setAdapter(occupationAdapter);
    mOccupation.setKeyListener(null);
    mOccupation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //mOccupation.setText(null);
            ((AutoCompleteTextView) view).showDropDown();
            return;
        }
    });
```

I managed to put it all into a Textinputlayout with the following xml specifications:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/lo_occupation"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="occupation"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"<--this is the important part
        android:id="@+id/actv_occupation"
        android:ems="10"
        android:completionThreshold="0"<--this too
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It helped me:

```
private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextViewRFID; 

...
    autoCompleteTextViewRFID = binding.choiceFieldRFID;
    List<String> rfidArray = databaseManager.readCowsRFID();
    ArrayAdapter<String> rfidAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, rfidArray);
    autoCompleteTextViewRFID.setThreshold(1);
    autoCompleteTextViewRFID.setAdapter(rfidAdapter);
```

...

```
autoCompleteTextViewTypeRange.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        autoCompleteTextViewTypeRange.showDropDown();
        return true;
    });
```

XML:

```
            <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/typeRange"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I got a great solution to this. It's simple. This is just the drop-down and choosing from the options.

Make sure you add these two lines to XML.

`android:completionThreshold="0"`
`android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

**XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/select_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
        android:completionThreshold="0"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="Select an Area"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
area_autocomplete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        area.showDropDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: This will show dropdown, but user cannot then type in it.
This solution is better https://stackoverflow.com/a/60489021/1404257

Comment: As in the solution of Abdulmalek Dery (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60489021/2914140) (if change to click listener) it hides and shows the list on every click. I can enter letters.

Comment: Agree with @Haris, it hides cursor, but you can enter letters. It is because of `android:completionThreshold="0" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use this single line of code

```
autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(100);
```