# Kotlin OnTouchListener called but it does not override performClick

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener

How to override `performClick` in **Kotlin** to avoid warning?

```
next.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
        when (motionEvent.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                val icon: Drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity.applicationContext, R.drawable.layer_bt_next)
                icon.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
                next.setImageDrawable(icon)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                //view.performClick()
                next.setImageResource(R.drawable.layer_bt_next)
            }
        }
        return@OnTouchListener true
    })
```

`view.performClick` does not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, I solved my own problem by overriding the OnTouch listener.

```
override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (view) {
        next -> {
            Log.d("next", "yeyy")
            when (motionEvent.action){
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    val icon: Drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity.applicationContext, R.drawable.layer_bt_next)
                    icon.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
                    next.setImageDrawable(icon)
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    view.performClick()
                    next.setImageResource(R.drawable.layer_bt_next)
                }
            }
        }
        previous -> {
            //ingredients here XD
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

And in that way, I can call single onTouch and implement it to many button and also can use the onClick by :

```
view.performClick()
```

Don't forget to implement :

```
View.OnTouchListener
```

And set the listener :

```
next.setOnTouchListener(this)
previous.setOnTouchListener(this)
```

Comment: In AS 4.0 using Java with an EditText the warning persist even after adding the call to performClick inside the onTouch listener method, at least in my own code. I had to suppress the warning explicitly.

Comment: Whose listener did you overwrite? Why should it make any difference? Looks like fluke...

Comment: I like the approach but the warning persists

Answer (score 56):

Try this way :

```
 next.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            when (event?.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> //Do Something
            }

            return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
        }
    })
```

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: It should works . make sure you have proper parent which does not override the OnTouchListener

Comment: How did this get so many upvotes? It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Doesn't make difference to me at all. I think maybe Android Studio has been updated and keep showing the linting error

Comment: @LeonardoRick After adding the @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
the error got away as its a accessibility warning. refer this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345118/11493559

Answer (score 8):

I don't think your solution will actually solve them problem presented by the warning. The warning states that certain accessibility functions use `performClick()` to activate buttons. If you look in the `View` class, the `performClick()` funtions calls the `onClickListener` directly, meaning the code in the `onTouchListener` will not be executed (`next.setImageResource(R.drawable.layer_bt_next)`) for these accessibility functions, since the view will never be physically touched, and thus your `onTouch` code won't run. You have to do one of either:

1. Subclass the view you are setting the `onTouchListener` on, and override `performClick` to execute the code, or
2. Set an `onClickListener` on the view that executes the code.

You could just implement `onClickListener` in your onTouchListener class and manually call `onClick()` from your `onTouchListener` (where you have `view.performClick()` now), and then move your executable code to the `onClick` override. You would also have to set BOTH `onTouchListener` and `onClickListener` on your views.

Comment: Can you just give example in terms of code ? for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me. I have code that must not be executed onClick(). It's kind of progress indication for a long touch. Accessibility doesn't matter. If you can't touch you can't use it. Maybe I really have to ignore the warning.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan - The warning is for accessibility purposes, so if that is not important or relevant to you, then yes, you should ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is the same issue you saw, but since I found this page searching for my issue, I thought I'd add my experience to help others :)

In my case the warning was being generated because the nullable view could have been of type `Void`. Calling the following:

```
nullableView?.setOnTouchListener(this)
```

produced the error:

> Custom view Void has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick

Performing a null check and casting to a `View` before setting the listener solved for me in this case, since `View` will override `performClick`:

```
if (nullableView != null) (nullableView as View).setOnTouchListener(this)
```

Comment: Casting a sub-class of View as a View doesn't really solve the problem, it just fools the IDE.

Comment: You need to override `performClick()` in a custom view extending the targetView type. Then, call `performClick()` under touch event

Comment: @exploitr thats what we don't want, we don't want to create a customview

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of digging, and not being able to fix my variation of this issue with anything in this thread, I finally found a fix. Maybe it will work for some of you. I had this widget listener setter in my `MainActivity` `onCreate` function:

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvAnimalList).setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

Which results in the warnings:

- *'onTouch' lambda should call 'View#performClick' when a click is detected*
- *Custom view "TextView" has 'setOnTouchListener' called on it but does not override 'performClick'*

First, I added a call to `v.performClick()`, which got rid of the first warning. Like this:

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvAnimalList).setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    v.performClick()
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

I got rid of the second warning by changing the `findViewById` cast from `<TextView>` to `<View>`. Here's my warning-free result:

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.tvAnimalList).setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    v.performClick()
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private fun closeKeyboard(binding: ContollerMeterBinding) {
    binding.scrollView.apply {
        setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener { v, event ->
            if (event != null && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                val imm =
                    activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                val isKeyboardUp = imm.isAcceptingText
                if (isKeyboardUp) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.windowToken, 0)
                }
            }
            performClick()
            false
        })
    }
}
```

This works for me: (not directly related to onTouch event but yields the same warning, might be helpful to someone)

Answer (score -1):

```
 takePhotoButton.setOnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
            when (motionEvent.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    //when user touch down
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    //when user touch release
                }
            }
            true
        }
```