# Kotlin view setOnTouchListener not trigger( I have referenced all documents)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Two textviews belong to view.
When I use setOnTouchListener on the view, the touch only succeeds once out of multiple attempts.

When I use setOnTouchListener for textAprName which is part of the textview, the touch works fine.

I want to smoothly touch both textviews.

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
            var convertView:View? = convertView
            val context = parent.context
            val aprInfo = aprList[position]
            var textAprName: TextView? = null
            var textApr: TextView? = null
            var holder: AprItemHolder? = null
            if (convertView == null) {
                val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apr_item_view, parent, false)
                textAprName = convertView?.findViewById(R.id.text_apr_name) as TextView
                textApr = convertView?.findViewById(R.id.text_apr) as TextView
                holder = AprItemHolder()
                holder.textAprName = textAprName
                holder.textApr = textApr
                convertView.tag = holder
            } else {
                holder = convertView.tag as AprItemHolder
                textAprName = holder.textAprName
                textApr = holder.textApr
            }
            textAprName?.text = aprInfo.name
            textApr?.text = aprInfo.description

            convertView?.setOnTouchListener @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility"){ v, event ->
                var action: Int = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)
                when (action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        StandElin.instance!!.SendApr(aprInfo.name)
                        closeDialog()
                    }
                }
                true
            }
            return convertView
}
```

about layout.apr_item_view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="289dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_apr1">

    <com.dkms.elin7.view.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_apr_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="APR 1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:font="@string/font_gotham_book" />

    <com.dkms.elin7.view.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_apr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Stand,110,0"
        android:textColor="@color/apr_text"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:font="@string/font_gotham_book" />
```

I converted the java project to kotlin.

It worked in the existing java, but not in kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

There's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170075/kotlin-ontouchlistener-called-but-it-does-not-override-performclick) like yours.

You can do following way also.

```
convertView.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> //Do Something
        }

        return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
    }
})
```

I think `onTouchListener` doesn't work the way you wrote. I found a [link](https://androidpedia.net/en/knowledge-base/47170075/kotlin-ontouchlistener-called-but-it-does-not-override-performclick) where you will find your answer more clearly.

**Edited** : Your source code is correctly working. I think I have understand where you are getting "error". You are actually getting "error" on `convertView`. You want to set `onTouchListener` while touching the view. But, error is you are unable to call `convertView`. I don't know why cause, you gave little source code. That's why I am unable to understand why?

Now, I can give alternative answer.

I want you to add `id` to that `Relativelayout` which you implement here. Then, call that layout. Suppose, `id` of that layout is `view`. Then, implement following source code to that kotlin adapter

```
view.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> //Do Something
        }

        return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
    }
})
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: No error occurred.
If you click two textviews, it does not work, and if you click a little longer at the end of the layout, it works.

Comment: @drogba See my edited answer. I think it will work now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that views don't overlap?

Try to use `convertView?.setOnClickListener { }` instead of `convertView?.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> }`