# Include view after if-condition

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have to different subviews I want to include in my view like this in my XML-File:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"/>

    <!--Include this as default and if user swipes right-->
    <include layout="@layout/dashboard_user_view" android:id="duv"/>
    <!--Include this if the user swipes left-->
    <include layout="@layout/dashboard_widgets_view" android:id="dwv"/>
```

Including one layout works fine, but now I want to switch between both of them.

So then I added the *OnSwipeTouchListener* from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures/19506010) tutorial, and I call it in my Kotlin class like this:

```
val myLayout = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.myLayout)
    myLayout.setOnTouchListener(object : OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        override fun onSwipeRight() {
            //TODO
        }
        override fun onSwipeLeft() {
            //TODO
        }
        override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        }
    })
```

This gives me an error which says:

> CustomView "RelativeLayout" has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override...

So how do I put the if-statement to determine which view to show in my Kotlin Class? Or do I put it in my XML? And how will the swiping action work that way?

(I hope you understand my problem)

Comment: Does it say "...but does not override `performClick`"? It must be a warning not an error.

Comment: @LieForBananas yeah i just don't know what that means

Comment: You can actually see the full explanation if you follow the link in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about `performClick()` you could read accepted answer here [android Button has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107105/android-button-has-setontouchlistener-called-on-it-but-does-not-override-perform).

But about these questions:

> So how do I put the if-statement to determine which view to show in my
>   Kotlin Class? Or do I put it in my XML? And how will the swiping
>   action work that way?

The "tutorial" that you point on is not good for your goal I think. Better read about [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide).